# android simple form taking data from form

Tags: android

So I've created a form and I want to send that data from form using a button. In activity_main.xml I created the design, some textboxs and a button. Now where I write the code to send the data to a gmail? Like, I'm new to android but how I take the data from every textbox?

Comment: The documentation for EditText might be a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

Inside your button `onClick()` method you should get text from `TextView` or `EditText` that you want data from like this

```
String name=textviewName.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `String name = editTextName.getText().toString();` for every editText and you can do whatever you want with String object.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read a little bit from the Android docs.

```
edittext.getText();
```

[Android docs on EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Answer (score 0):

> To Mail Something Which is present on your Text Field , you can use below content ..

use this code to that Activity where the values present and send button..
sendEmail is Email Send Btn ID

```
protected void sendEmail() { 
Log.i("Send email", "");
String[] TO = {""};
String[] CC = {""};
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " Your Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Your Text Here"+((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID)).
            getText().toString());
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    finish();
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(CurrentActivityName.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

you can use multiple TextView Values or EditText Values in EXTRA_TEXT by Joining + sign.

Comment: edit your currentActivityName .. in ur case that is MainActivity